# What does brackets and parentheses after jquery selector mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I ran into this line of code and I can't figure out what it means:

```
$("#theAppContainer")[s > u ? "addClass" : "removeClass"]("something");
```

I understand the first part is selecting the element called theAppContainer and the second part evaluates to "addClass" if s > u, but I can't figure out what this line of code does overall.

Comment: It's a ternary operator, like an  if/else, so if `s` is greater than `u`, then select addClass etc.

Comment: As a sidenote, it should be noted that toggleClass has a switch, so you could just do `$("#theAppContainer").toggleClass('something', s > u);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The bracket syntax gets the value of a property by name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), and the parentheses call the function that is the value of that property. It’s equivalent to:

```
var container = $('#theAppContainer');

if(s > u) {
    container.addClass('something');
} else {
    container.removeClass('something');
}
```

Also, please never write code like that. =)

Also also, [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) takes a second `switch` argument that you can use instead:

```
$('#theAppContainer').toggleClass('something', s > u);
```

Comment: I do like ternary's a lot, but in this case, ya it's kind of ridiculous haha, agreed!

Comment: I dunno, I kinda like it.  It's not even the craziest bit of JQuery single-lining I've seen!  [From a performance standpoint](http://jsperf.com/ternary-vs-if-using-jquery), at least, they're almost identical.

Comment: @SandyGifford: Performance should be the last standpoint to consider! Anyways, I’ve added the jQuery-esque way of doing things. Thanks for making me look :)

Comment: I mean, let's be real here for a second.  If you're on JSPerf, you're being anal retentive enough as-is.  We don't have to pretend it's logical to shave 1/1000th of a second off of your script, but we do it anyway.  Not even the perfinator could give this sort of pattern the edge, though. =p

Answer (score 5):

`$("#theAppContainer")` returns a jquery object.

`jqueryObject["addClass"]` is synonymous with `jqueryObject.addClass`

So, `jqueryObject["addClass"]` returns the addClass method on the jquery object.

Then you use `("something")` to pass parameters into and execute the method.

So you're essentially doing

```
var myJqueryObject = $("#theAppContainer");
if(s > u) {
    myJqueryObject.addClass("something");
}
else {
    myJqueryObject.removeClass("something");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Square Bracket** notation.

`$('#element')['hide'](700)`

**Dot** notation:

`$('#element').hide(700)`

the other thing **( ? : )** is called `ternary operator`

that makes a statement comparison returning a boolean value,
Where `s>u` is a statement, and depending on the result the values are used:

`STATEMENT ? IF TRUE USE THIS : IF FALSE USE THAT ;`

if `s > u` use `'addClass'` else use `'removeClass'`
which means that you'll get `$("#theAppContainer")["addClass"]("something");` if `s > u` and
`$("#theAppContainer")["removeClass"]("something");` if `s===u || s<u` 
which can be translated in DOT notation in:

```
$("#theAppContainer").addClass("something");
```

or

```
$("#theAppContainer").removeClass("something");
```

This is not the best way to do it, cause you can use `toggleClass()` method in that particular case, but any way it's good to know.

And it's not true that you should not use bracket notation. In advanced JS you'll see all the benefits.

Comment: If you’re talking about my answer, I didn’t say never to use bracket notation. It’s just a silly choice in this case.